# Exclude keys that are instances of any class from an object type

Tags: typescript, types

I need a utility type that takes any object type and excludes all keys that are instances of any class from it. Use case: I have some ORM classes and want to extract all columns and skip relations. Is there a way to match any class in a type condition?

```
class A {}

class B {}

type MyType = {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    n: number,
    str: string
}

type ExcludeClasses<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends { new(): any } ? never : K]: T[K]
}

type test = ExcludeClasses<MyType> // this should not contain a and b
```

`Omit` works, but listing keys manually for every single ORM class is not ideal. Another solution would be to define a union for types used in the ORM and reverse the condition. But then I might forget some type

```
type ExcludeClasses<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends AllOrmTypes ? K: never]: T[K]
}
```

Comment: A and B aren't class constructors. They're the types of the instances.

Comment: Given the above, it's hard to tell what you're asking... Since you never actually had "classes" in `MyType` in the first place. Would you ask how to *get* the actual class types in there, or  would you still want to somehow remove `A` and B`? The latter is impossible unless you use a union type to filter like you said.

Comment: does `{ a: A }` technically mean that `A` is an instance of class `A`? anyway, yes. I want to get rid of all instances

Comment: `A`, the *type*, represents the type for instances of *class* `A`. You can't tell if a type is supposed to be the type of an instance of a class or not. Like you said, you need a union type with all the types to filter out first.

Comment: Classes in ECMAScript are mostly just syntax sugar on top of the existing "function with a prototype field" method of inheritance. As a consequence, there is currently no reliable way for TypeScript to generally differentiate between "a class instance" and "a plain object". I think your best bet is probably to build a union type of all your ORM classes, perhaps automatically generated somehow if possible.